# delete rows from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, delete-row, sql-delete

I'm trying to use SQL to delete multiple rows from multiple tables that are
joined together.

Table A is joined to Table B
Table B is joined to Table C

I want to delete all rows in table B & C that correspond to a row in Table A

```
CREATE TABLE `boards` (
  `boardid` int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `boardname` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`boardid`)
);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `messages`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `messageid` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `boardid` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `topicid` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`messageid`)
);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `topics`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `topics` (
  `topicid` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `boardid` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `topicname` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `author` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`topicid`)
);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, if you had used InnoDB tables, you could set up a [cascading delete with foreign keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) that would do it all automatically. But if you have some reason for using MyISAM, You just use a [multiple-table DELETE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html):

```
DELETE FROM boards, topics, messages
USING boards INNER JOIN topics INNER JOIN messages
WHERE boards.boardid = $boardid
    AND topics.boardid = boards.boardid
    AND messages.boardid = boards.boardid;
```

Comment: Why "USING" and not "ON"?

Comment: what if the table has more than 50M records?

Answer (score 6):

this can be done by your db-system if you are using foreign keys with "on delete cascade".

Take a look here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Answer (score 2):

You could either just check for presence

```
delete from topics where boardid in (select boardid from boards)
delete from messages where boardid in (select boardid from boards)
```

but this would only make sense if this behaviour should not always apply.  When the behaviour should always apply, implement foreign keys with delete on cascade

explained on a zillion sites, in your helpfiles and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key#CASCADE)

Answer (score 1):

Deleting rows from multiple tables can be done in two ways :

- Delete rows from one table, determining which rows to delete by referring to another
  table
- Delete rows from multiple tables with a single statement

---

Multiple-table DELETE statements can be written in two formats. The following example demonstrates one syntax, for a query that deletes rows from a table t1 where the id values match those in a table t2:

```
DELETE t1 FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id;
```

The second syntax is slightly different:

```
DELETE FROM t1 USING t1, t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id;
```

To delete the matching records from both tables, the statements are:

```
DELETE t1, t2 FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id;
DELETE FROM t1, t2 USING t1, t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id;
```

The ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses normally supported by UPDATE and DELETE aren’t allowed when these statements are used for multiple-table operations.