# What's wrong with the query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete, cascade, cascading-deletes

What's wrong with the query?

```
delete from categories c
left join categories_products cp on cp.category_id = c.id
left join products p on p.id = cp.product_id
left join images i on i.object_id = cp.product_id
where c.id = 3 and i.site_section = 'products'
```

MySQL returns error. I'm trying to execute this query through the HeidiSQL. Error is unknown.

Another question, which will also help me: how can I make cascade deletion of row if I have no indexes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should add the alias after the `delete` keyword

```
DELETE c FROM categories c
          LEFT JOIN categories_products cp 
                    on cp.category_id = c.id
          LEFT JOIN products p 
                    on p.id = cp.product_id
          LEFT JOIN images i on i.object_id = cp.product_id
WHERE c.id = 3 and i.site_section = 'products'
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm trying to delete row in 'c', 'cp' and 'i' tables, and row deleted only from 'c'.

Comment: this link might help you :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734567/delete-rows-from-multiple-tables

Comment: Thanks, the idea is clear. It's just many aliases after DELETE keyword :)

Answer (score 1):

```
delete c from categories c
left join categories_products cp on cp.category_id = c.id
left join products p on p.id = cp.product_id
left join images i on i.object_id = cp.product_id
where c.id = 3 and i.site_section = 'products'
```

When joining you have to specify from what table you are deleting. That is why it is `delete c from ...`