# Laravel: How to delete rows from multiple table with same id with only 1 query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have this code to delete data from multiple tables in one go:

```
DB::table('tb_stikes_register_school')->where('register_id', $_POST['id'])->delete();
            DB::table('tb_stikes_register_guardian')->where('register_id', $_POST['id'])->delete();
            DB::table('tb_stikes_register_student')->where('register_id', $_POST['id'])->delete();
```

I'm trying to shorten this into 1 query only, register_id from `guardian` and `school` tables is the foreign key of `student` table. I've been trying to use join but only `student` table record is deleted. Is there any workaround this?

Comment: Do you try to delete this when you are deleting a student?

Comment: No, the `register_student` table is independent (it has no model). The role of that table is only to store registration data given by users (which i split into three, register_student, register_guardian, register_school), and has nothing to do with real student data and/or model.

Comment: the "only student table record is deleted" i mentioned in the question is referring to `tb_stikes_register_student`

Comment: Have you tried using `->select('*')` when using the JOIN? Otherwise an option could be to put table constraint on the migrations, such as `->onDelete('cascade')`

Comment: @clod986: `onDelete('cascade')` works, thanks. Using `select('*')` won't help by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this maybe - haven't tested

```
DB::table(DB::raw('FROM tb_stikes_register_school, tb_stikes_register_guardian, tb_stikes_register_student'))
->join(ENTER JOIN INFO) // wasn't clear how your tables were related
->where('register_id', $_POST['id'])
->delete();
```

Or you could use a fully raw query:

```
 DB::query('SQL statement here');
```

Basically recreating something similar to this: [delete rows from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734567/delete-rows-from-multiple-tables)

Comment: That is exactly how I did it first time, with the student's `register_id` joined with school and guardian's `register_id`, and look where student's `register_id` is same as `$_POST['id']`.But with this method only records from `tb_stikes_register_student` is deleted. What I want is the record with same `register_id` `guardian` and `school` record is also deleted. This question actually has been solved, see above comments, thanks for your time.