# How do I delete many rows at once in my Laravel application

Tags: php, forms, laravel, post

I am developing a Laravel application.

There are a lot of CRUD sample application on the internet.

Most of them are like this,

- create  GET  articles/create
- update  POST articles/store
- edit    GET  articles/{id}/edit
- show    GET  articles/{id}
- delete  POST articles/{id}/destroy

Generally it works fine.

But as for delete, I am developing an application that can enable multiple row deletion at once.

I tried to loop this function for the first time, and found that it is not good idea to execute form post again and again.

```
<form method="post" action="/articles/{{$aaa->id}}/destroy">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">         
</form>
```

How do I delete many rows at once in my Laravel application?

Are there any solutions?

Comment: If you're using 4.1 then may be it will be solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624630/mass-delete-in-laravel-4-1-based-on-array-of-ids-or-objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible option can be.

```
$ids_to_delete = array("1","5","8");
DB::table('table_name')->whereIn('id', $ids_to_delete)->delete(); 

$ids_to_delete = array("1","5","8");
Table::destroy($ids_to_delete);
```

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to make array of the delete "id" and send it to the destroy method regarding controller.

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    Case::find(explode(',', $id))->delete();
 }
```

OR

```
 Case::destroy($ids);
```

Hope this is help.

Thnaks.