# In laravel, how to delete fixed number of rows from table using query builder?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to delete any five rows from my *users* table. I used following code for that.

```
DB::table('users')->take(5)->delete();
```

But it deletes all rows in that table. How will I overcome this problem?

Comment: Take a look at this you will get your answer [Mass delete in Laravel 4.1, based on array of ids or objects](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23626070/4757316)

Comment: You can't delete rows like that. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: U can take first 5 records and then check if user.id is IN and delete them

Comment: @GONG: I could take any number of records, by I cannot delete selected number of records. That is my problem

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin: I just want to remove any five records randomly for my project

Comment: @manoos i mean something like this
`$users = DB::table('users')->select('id')->take(5)->get();
DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', $users)->delete();`

Comment: @manoos, I see. I've updated my answer with tested solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said you want to delete 5 rows **randomly**, in this case this will work, I've tested it:

```
DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', DB::table('users')->orderBy(DB::raw("RAND()"))->take(5)->lists('id'))->delete();
```

It will take 5 random IDs and then will delete rows with these IDs with just two queries:

```
select `id` from `users` order by RAND() asc limit 5
delete from `users` where `id` in ('786', '186', '82', '578', '232')
```

Comment: How will I implement my condition using where() ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use rand() function and delete users this way

```
DB::table('users')->DB::table('users')->orderby(RAND())->take(5)->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach`

```
$users = DB::table("users")->orderBy(DB::raw("RAND()"))->take(5)->get();
foreach($users as $user){
    DB::table("users")->where("id", $user->id)->delete();
}
```

Comment: tahnks for your reply.  I am just trying to delete rows without foreach.  Is there any option?

Comment: why not just select only ids and delete them with whereIn?

Comment: @GONG yes, could be so).. 

@manoos try change ```take``` to ```limit```

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', DB::table('users')->take(5)->lists('id'))->delete();
```