# Laravel how to delete a row from multiple tables in one query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, delete-row

In my question answers project, the admin has a functionality to view all questions and delete each one if he wishes. but one question id has 5 related tables. that is , each question id is present in 5 tables in db and when admin deletes one question i have to delete all the entries from these 5 tables based on this question id.

in my controller

```
DB::table('user_questions')->where('question_id','=',$question_id)->delete();  
DB::table('masters_answers')->where('question_id','=',$question_id)->delete();  
DB::table('masters_questions')->where('question_id','=',$question_id)->delete(); 
DB::table('question_to_category')->where('question_id','=',$question_id)->delete(); 
DB::table('question_to_tags')->where('question_id','=',$question_id)->delete(); 
return Redirect::action('AdminController@anyShowQuestions', array());
```

The above code will works but is there any way for do the same procedure in one db query in laravel.? i had referred this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21747529/laravel-how-to-delete-rows-from-multiple-table-with-same-id-with-only-1-query) but cannot find a solution for mine. it will be so helpful if anyone suggest a right way??

Comment: Since the records are all related you could set up foreign key constraints and set `ON DELETE` to `CASCADE`

Answer (score 0):

You can set your foreign keys properly on this related tables. Add `onDelete('cascade')` when you are creating keys in migrations and if everything is ok, then, when you delete the question it would automatically delete the related items too.

**OR**

Use the `DB::statement`expression with the respective SQL query.

Example:

```
DB::statement('update foo set bar=2');
```

You would need to solve your task in plain SQL, and then put the resulting query in the `DB::statement` and viola.

To help you with the query, you can read this [article](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/article/mysql/cross-table-delete/) or this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331992/how-to-delete-from-multiple-tables-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Setting foreign keys on your tables would be the cleanest solution

Alternatively, if you can't use foreign keys, you can use [Model Events](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#model-events).

Each of your models fires several events, allowing you to hook into various points in the model's lifecycle, including the `delete` event. Use something like this in your model:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public static function boot()
    {
        //execute the parent's boot method 
        parent::boot();

        //delete your related models here, for example
        static::deleted(function($user)
        {
            foreach($user->user_profiles as $profile)
            {
                $profile->delete();
            } 
        }

    }

}
```

Now every time a `User` gets deleted, all of the atatched `User_Profile` weill be deleted as well.