# Run many mySQL queries through php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with many tables. On side 1, I have a button that passes me to side 2. On side 2, I want the code to remove every row in every named table that has a specific `pid` that I have stored in a variable. I have a code on side 2 but it doesn't do anything.

**Code on side 2:**

```
$pid3 = $_POST['pid2'];

$del = "DELETE FROM answer_det WHERE pid='$pid3'";
$del .= "DELETE FROM project WHERE pid='$pid3'";
$del .= "DELETE FROM question WHERE pid='$pid3'";
$del .= "DELETE FROM respondent WHERE pid='$pid3'";
$del .= "DELETE FROM result WHERE pid='$pid3'";
$del .= "DELETE FROM users WHERE pid='$pid3'";

$run = mysqli_query($mysqli,$del);

if($run)
{
   echo "<h1>Project is deleted!</h1>";
}
```

Comment: Better than sanitizing, use prepared statements with placeholders.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/mysqli_multi_query)

```
$pid3 = $_POST['pid2'];

$del = "DELETE FROM answer_det WHERE pid='$pid3';";
$del .= "DELETE FROM project WHERE pid='$pid3';";
$del .= "DELETE FROM question WHERE pid='$pid3';";
$del .= "DELETE FROM respondent WHERE pid='$pid3';";
$del .= "DELETE FROM result WHERE pid='$pid3';";
$del .= "DELETE FROM users WHERE pid='$pid3';";

$run = mysqli_multi_query($mysqli,$del);

if($run)
{
   echo "<h1>Project is deleted!</h1>";
}
```

Comment: This is going to fail because there is no separation between queries.  The string will be `DELETE FROM answer_det WHERE pid='$pid3'DELETE FROM project WHERE pid='$pid3'` and so on.

Comment: Complementing @Devon's comment, it's missing `;` at the end of each one..

Comment: Thanks @Devon, FirstOne.

Comment: @NanaPartykar, upvoted now that it's fixed.  This should be the right answer for the OP.

Comment: Thanks @Devon, for finding out the mistake. *I'm embarrass*

Comment: This is also incorrect because it only checks the result of the first query, not the five later queries.  So the deletion from project, question, respondent, result, or users might fail but `$run` would still be true.  Further, if you do things this way, you can't do any more queries on the `$mysqli` connection, because it is still waiting for you to process the subsequent results.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider altering your mysql tables where `pid` exists to have that field as a foreign key which cascades on delete. Something like

```
ALTER TABLE `answer_det` 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (pid) 
REFERENCES table_where_pid_is_the_primary_key (pid)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

replacing `answer_det` with the other table names to create keys there too. If you don't have access to alter the tables then likely your queries are failing because you are missing semicolons to separate them:

```
$del = "DELETE FROM answer_det WHERE pid='$pid3';";
$del .= "DELETE FROM project WHERE pid='$pid3';";
$del .= "DELETE FROM question WHERE pid='$pid3';";
$del .= "DELETE FROM respondent WHERE pid='$pid3';";
$del .= "DELETE FROM result WHERE pid='$pid3';";
$del .= "DELETE FROM users WHERE pid='$pid3';";
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could just run one query, with joins, something like this:

```
$pid3 = $_POST['pid2'];

$del = "DELETE a,b,c,d,e,f FROM answer_det a "
$del .= "JOIN project b on b.pid=a.pid "
$del .= "JOIN question c  on c.pid=a.pid "
$del .= "JOIN respondent d on d.pid=a.pid "
$del .= "JOIN result e on e.pid=a.pid "
$del .= "JOIN users f on f.pid=a.pid "
$del .= "WHERE a.pid='$pid3'";

$run = mysqli_query($mysqli,$del);

if($run)
{
   echo "<h1>Project is deleted!</h1>";

}
```

[How to delete from multiple tables in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331992/how-to-delete-from-multiple-tables-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

simplify  your query as given below

```
$pid3 = $_POST['pid2'];    
 $del= DELETE FROM answer_det 't1',project 't2',question 't3' USING t1, t2,t3 WHERE t3.pid = t2.pid and t1.pid = t2.pid AND t1.pid =  $pid3
$run = mysqli_query($mysqli,$del);
if($run)
{
echo "<h1>Project is deleted!</h1>";
}
```

refer. [delete rows from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734567/delete-rows-from-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 0):

[There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839905/mysql-delete-from-multiple-tables-with-one-query)'s a good solution:

`DELETE t1, t2 FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 INNER JOIN t3
WHERE t1.id=t2.id AND t2.id=t3.id;`

Answer (score -1):

You were missing the semi-colon at the end of the query. You need to put ';' after each query in order to execute multiple queries together.

Try this:

```
$pid3="1";

$del = "DELETE FROM answer_det WHERE pid='$pid3';";
$del .= "DELETE FROM project WHERE pid='$pid3';";
$del .= "DELETE FROM question WHERE pid='$pid3';";
$del .= "DELETE FROM respondent WHERE pid='$pid3';";
$del .= "DELETE FROM result WHERE pid='$pid3';";
$del .= "DELETE FROM users WHERE pid='$pid3';";

echo $del
```

Comment: Even though that's important, that alone won't solve the problem without [mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/mysqli_multi_query).